# How to add active class to the navigation link in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have added one category in navigation and  other links in it. But when I cick on the category menu it will having active class and if I click on other links it does not have active class.  So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into your top.phml file in your theme since that is where your top menu items render, you could override something there to add your active state.

app / design / frontend / default / THEMENAME / template / catalog / navigation / top.phtml

Comment: i have checked for that but it is not an issue.